# Стоит ли использовать Angular 1?

Tags: angularjs, веб-программирование, angular2

Делаю веб-приложение с расчётом на длительную перспективу. Решил изначально использовать Angular 2, но мне не понравилось, что он слишком массивный, создаёт много файлов и директорий, а так-же устанавливает много модулей, которые мне не нужны (а нужны исключительно для работы ангуляра 2), тем самым, вовсе не вписывается в общую арххитектуру приложения. А за основу своего приложения, брать Angular 2 я не буду, так как его роль далеко не первостепенна. Но я вот вспомнил, что первый ангуляр просто подключается ссылочкой и работает сразу же. Но возникает вопрос, а Ангуляр 1, это вообще хороший продукт, а то я начитался об огромных преимуществах Ангуляра 2, над своим младшим братом, что возникает вопрос, стоит ли вообще использовать Ангуляр1? 
Или лучше обойтись православным JQuery и не морочить себе голову? 
Или быть может есть какой-то такой же простенький фреймворк (библиотека), чтобы просто подключить его ссылочкой и не собирать по частям, не закачивать какие-то дополнительные возможности, а просто сесть с сделать то что мне нужно?

Comment: При разрастании проекта с Angular 1 начнётся боль. С вторым попроще, его модульность это не проблема, наоборот, не стоит бояться этого. В плане чего-то поменьше, я давно использовал KnockoutJS, может он Вам подойдёт, но я не знаю как он развивается сейчас. И маленькое замечание, Angular - это фреймворк, а всякие jQuery и KnockoutJS это просто библиотеки.

Comment: Если фреймворк "не вписывается в общую арххитектуру приложения", то он явно не подходит, либо архитектура выбрана неверно. Как справедливо заметил @Umed - JQuery это просто библиотека (при чем идеологически почти противоположная подходу в Angular2, т.к. в нем прямая манипуляция DOM в 99% случаев противопоказана), она не навязывает вам каких-то подходов и концепций. Ангуляр другое дело,  вы следуете определенным правилам, и получаете магию и удовольствие от модулей, компонент и тайпскрипта за компанию :)

Comment: А насчет размера. У нас в проекте ~200 файлов (1.2мб) кода, это без всяких assets и глобал styles. На выходе при production сборке с AOT - 170Kb bundle. По нынешним временам по моему весьма скромно.

Comment: @Dimanoid, а как выбрать архитектуру правильно?

Comment: @Bim_Bam мне кажется это уже отдельный философский вопрос :) Я просто хотел сказать, что если архитектура известна, а инструмент не подходит... одно из двух имеет смысл поменять.